# How to get the data for the next two weeks?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've several straight-forward planners, like this:

```
| date       | person | person 2 | description |  
 2013-03-01      peter      pam    painting  
 2013-03-18      john       carl   cleaning  
 2013-03-20      max        anne   washing
```

On a different sheet, I want to filter the 'events' for the next 2 weeks only. How can I achieve this? I tried several ways, but none of them are working.

With `=ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS360(B2:B;NOW()))` I can get a daynumber in a different column. 0 = today, 1 = yesterday, -1 tomorrow et cetera. In fact, I need to filter the days -1 to -14. Sometimes there are only 2 events, sometimes 5 in 2 weeks.

**Edit:** Some things I found

- First, I filter the correct daynumbers with    `=filter(A2:A50;A2:A50>-14;A2:A50<0)`
- Then, I do a vlookup `=vlookup(G32,A1:E49;5;false)`
  (where G32 is the filtercommand, A2:A50 the daynumbers, A1:E49 all the data)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity for the [QUERY](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882) command and [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

I'm assuming your data is in 4 columns, A:D, in "sheet 1".

```
=query('sheet 1'!A:D,"select * where datediff( A, now()) < 14 and datediff( A, now()) > 0")
```